# Natively add available languages to be selected on a React-Native Expo App

Tags: react-native, expo

I am developing an app with Expo.

I am using `i18next` npm library for multilingual support, and I know how to grab the preferred locales by:

`import * as Localization from 'expo-localization';`

`Localization.locales` or `Localization.locale`

I have implemented an in-app language change with `AsyncStorage`.

But on iOS, apart from in-app language change, I observe that most apps' language can be changed through system settings like this.

[image: iOS system]

In this case, how do my Expo app let iOS know what languages are supported by my app? Also, is `Localization.locale` synchronized to the selected language through iOS settings?

(I am not an Android user) How about Android? Is the case similar? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In Expo, you can show this settings for your app by doing this.

in `app.json` or `app.config.js` add these properties inside `infoPlist` property

Example:-

```json
{
"expo":{
  "ios": {
      "infoPlist": {
        "CFBundleAllowMixedLocalizations": true,
        "CFBundleLocalizations": ["en", "ar"],//add in this array the languages that your app supports
        "CFBundleDevelopmentRegion": "en"
      }
    },
  }
}
```

And also add the locales paths under `expo` property

Full example:-

```json
{
"expo":{
"locales": {
      "en": "./locale/en.json",
      "ar": "./locale/ar.json"
    },
  "ios": {
      "infoPlist": {
        "CFBundleAllowMixedLocalizations": true,
        "CFBundleLocalizations": ["en", "ar"],//add in this array the languages that your app supports
        "CFBundleDevelopmentRegion": "en"
      }
    },
  }
}
```

*Note: this solution will work on your app after the build and the languages options will not show on Expo go, since it supports only English*

Answer (score -1):

It is platform specific feature which you can't change from React Native you can only read this data and change your app language based on these settings. For example with https://gitlab.com/os-team/libs/utils/-/tree/master/packages/i18next-react-native-language-detector

```js
import { LanguageDetectorModule } from 'i18next';
import { Platform, NativeModules } from 'react-native';

const RNLanguageDetector: LanguageDetectorModule = {
  type: 'languageDetector',
  init: () => {},
  detect: () => {
    const locale =
      Platform.OS === 'ios'
        ? NativeModules.SettingsManager.settings.AppleLocale ||
          NativeModules.SettingsManager.settings.AppleLanguages[0] // iOS 13
        : NativeModules.I18nManager.localeIdentifier;
    return locale.split('_')[0];
  },
  cacheUserLanguage: () => {},
};

export default RNLanguageDetector;
```

To set a list of locales in your app you need to add it in Xcode

[image]

[image]